# How to call your module in your form using VB6.0?

Tags: sql, vb6

I've a question regarding modules in VB6.0. I want to use module to separate my SQL connection in my form. In my `form1` I have this below code :

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

test

End Sub

Private Sub test()
Dim cn As New ADODB.connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

cn.ConnectionString = "SQL CONNECTION"
cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient 
cn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
cn.Open

Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT Statement")

Set dcbo.RowSource = rs
dcbo.ListField = "fieldname"
dcbo.BoundColumn = "column name"

cn.Close

End Sub
```

Create a Module Form `module1`. How do I separate my `ConnectionString` using that module and call it to my `Form1`?

Comment: Good question. Just improved a bit of formatting to make to more readable.

Comment: Did you see the answer my below - was it useful ?

Comment: Don't forget we answer questions on stackoverflow for points - please tick the answer or vote it up if it helped you at all.

Answer (score 0):

you are asking a very fundamental question so it looks like you are a beginner to VB6.  You should know that there are more modern languages similar to VB6, and VB.Net is the current supported language from Microsoft and was the successor to VB6. That said, VB is also a useful tool when used in Windows Scripting etc so you can still benefit from learning it.

You may want to read a web-based tutorial such as http://www.vbtutor.net/vbtutor.html but there are many other VB6 resources available on the web from those for new developers to those for experts.

To answer your question, for making variables declared in one module be available elsewhere VB has the 'Public' keyword to use instead of 'dim'.

```
' module
option explicit
public cn As New ADODB.connection

' form
Private Sub Form_Load()
cn.ConnectionString = "SQL CONNECTION"
cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient 
cn.ConnectionTimeout = 0
cn.Open

Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT Statement")

...

cn.Close
end sub

'  You can use the cn connection later 
sub SomeTimeLater()
cn.Open

Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT Statement")

...

cn.Close

end sub
```

Notes:

1. Put `option explicit` at the top of all of your files (forms,
   modules) as this will indicate any undeclared variables which
   reduces mistakes and saves your time.
2. Think about closing the connection each time you use it as holding
   open a SQL connection can be a performance issue.

There are many more great things to learn about VB to help you be an effective and efficient programmer so please read some of those on-line resources as StackOverflow is not a learning resource.